# Gifting specific apps from within an app

Tags: ios, app-store

A client has asked us to create an app for iOS that gifts other apps to their customers. I.e. a customer downloads the app, in which some paid App Store app are offered for free. The fee is paid by our client.

Essentially, it should work pretty much like Apple's 12 days of Christmas app.

I can't find any way to achieve this. There apparently is no way to forward an app's purchase to another Apple ID.

Did I miss any obvious API or SDK to make this possible? Or can't this be done?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done for paid apps.  If you control all apps you can make the apps free with in app purchase and then use another app to "gift the in app purchase". You would have to fully implement the gifting mechanism through your servers.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. Unfortunately, we don't control the other apps, as they're from other developers.